# Ractive js: Component instances still active after teardown, with nested object lists

Tags: ractivejs

While developing an approach for controlling automagic dom placement of nested object lists within #each template sections(as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34864413/5807270)), I ran into a separate issue:

Ractive component instances, in this scenario automagic binding and iterating over parent nested object lists, do not seem to be de-referenced or de-commisioned post teardown events. The result is that while the component instance is successfully un-rendered, it still appears to receive and process data changes(onchange) associated with its prior keypath binding. If you perform a findAllComponents from the parent context, the component instance is still listed in the returned array.

In my use case of mutliple adds and "deletes" of associated nested object list keys and component instances, I accumulate an ever growing list of active instances, even though most have been torn down.

So a few questions:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. If it is expected, wouldn't this create potential memory leaks and processing overhead from "phantom" component instances, since the instances still seem to be bound in use?
3. If it is not expected behavior, is there some other activity required on the component teardown event processing to "de-bind" the component instance from the parent and/or its associated keypath?
   (I have tried setting the specific object nest key to null, but the computed (data functions since this is a nested list) functions seem to continue to process this member and throw console message errors/warnings on the nulled key.)

Comment: As you describe it, this looks like a bug to me. You can report it to [Ractive issues](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues). It may be nice to produce a jsfiddle, codepen or similar demonsrating this with minimal code.